# ¿Cómo miro si dos arrays tienen los mismos valores, aunque sea en diferente orden?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo 2 arrays con el mismo contenido (valores "1" y "2"):

```
var array = ["1","2"];
var array2 = ["2","1"];
var total = [];
```

Hice un bucle "for" para detectar si alguno coincide con otro:

```
for(i<0; i<array2.length;i++;{
    if(array[i]==array1[i]{
        total.push(array[i])
}
```

Sin embargo, nunca se va a pushear porque el primer elemento de cada array es diferente:

```
array[0] = "1";
array1[0] = "2";
```

¿Hay alguna solución para solucionar ese problema? ¿Para hacer que coincida? ¿Alguna función?

Comment: Tienes mal escrito el for, te falta el paréntesis de cierre

Comment: Hola! Gracias por decirmelo, el codigo en el Visual esta bien, pasa que esta fue mi primera pregunta en este sitio. Soy nuevo,  y escribi mal y apurado, la proxima lo tendre en cuenta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion indexOf para saber si un elemento del array2 se encuentra en el array1

```
for(i<0; i<array2.length;i++;{
 const exist= array1.indexOf(array2[i])
 if(exist==-1){
   console.log("no existe")
 }
}
```

Comment: x-rw gracias! lo pude resolver!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que hay un error en como declaras el for, pues deberías declarar la variable i e inicializarla en 0.

```
    for(***let i = 0***; i<array2.length;i++;{
    if(array[i]==array1[i]{
        total.push(array[i])
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias! Es que es mi primera vez utilizando esta pagina, lo escribi mal y apurado, la proxima lo tendre en cuenta, gracias!

Comment: Es mi primer ayuda tb!

Answer (score 2):

Añado otra alternativa basada en **[ECMAScript 6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)** por si a alguien le sirve

```js
const arr1 = ['1', '2']
const arr2 = ['2', '1', '3']

const out = arr1.filter(x => arr2.some(c => x === c))
console.log(out)
```

Puedes realizar el **[filtro](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)** de tu primer arreglo y una vez dentro utilizas el método **[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some)** el cual te trae las coincidencias en el otro arreglo basado en la condición que deseas :D

Feliz Código!

Comment: Hola. Gracias por aportar!

Answer (score 2):

Solo quisiera hacer la anotación siguiente:

En caso de ocupar dos ciclos for, la complejidad es `O(nm)`, `n` siendo la longitud del primer arreglo y `m` la longitud del otro.

Aunque no lo parezca si utilizas funciones de javascript como `indexOf`, `filter`, `some`, etc... y tú solo estás escribiendo un for, aún así el algoritmo tiene complejidad `O(nm)` pues estos métodos tienen complejidad lineal, internamente escanean el arreglo hasta encontrar el elemento.

Si es importante el performance, quizá deberías usar un algoritmo (u otro lenguaje) con mejor comportamiento asintótico.

Yo propongo primero ordenar el arreglo que tenga más elementos, que tomaría tiempo `O(nlog(n))` y después iterar sobre el arreglo que tenga menos elementos y hacer binary search con el arreglo que tenga más elementos, que tomaría tiempo `O(mlog(n))`. Esto obviamente en términos de complejidad sería más conveniente, pero quizá no sea lo que se desee, en cualquier caso el orden se podría intercambiar.

Probablemente en javascript no se note la diferencia entre linear search y binary search, o quizá inclusive esto sea contradictorio pues actualmente JS no tiene implementado binary search de forma nativa, a diferencia de `indexOf` o las funciones ya mencionadas y como es un lenguaje interpretado inclusive podría llegar a ser contraproducente hacer binary search, o tal vez las ganancias de performance se noten cuando tienes muchísimos elementos. Pero si eso llegara a pasar, entonces quizá no sería cosa del algoritmo utilizado, sino del lenguaje.

En fin, era algo que quería comentar, espero a alguien le sirva de algo.

Comment: Gracias, si me ha servido!